# How do I get the MIME type of a file being requested in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httphandler

I would like to handle requests differently depending upon the MIME type. For example, I have PDF's, images and other media files that I would like to prohibit access to based on their respective MIME types. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks for the help.

I should also note that accessing the Windows registry is not an option for my application.

Comment: Is this in respect to restrictions on Upload of these files or download

Comment: This is in respect to download and/or URL rewriting.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET Core, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35880687.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

.NET's mime-type mappings are stored in the `System.Web.MimeMapping` class which offers the [GetMimeMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx) method.

Prior to .NET 4.5, this class was marked as `internal`, and thus not available to your code. In that case the best you can do is steal the list, which you can get using Reflector and decompile the static constructor (cctor).

If taking that approach, you may be better off simply creating a list of supported extensions and their mime type and storing it on a dictionary. (The list inside MimeMapping is a tad verbose)

Comment: That's exactly the route I took. I'm sure I missed some extensions, but they would most likely be corner cases best dealt with as they arise to satisfy the "being productive/working software" requirement LOL. Thanks for the suggestion! I never knew about the MimeMappings. Very cool!

Comment: As of 4.5, this class has gone public! With the convenient `GetMimeMapping(string fileName)` method. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem a few month ago and solved it with this simple wrapper-class around System.Web.MimeMapping (as mentioned by Richard Szalay):

```
/// <summary>
/// This class allows access to the internal MimeMapping-Class in System.Web
/// </summary>
class MimeMappingWrapper
{
    static MethodInfo getMimeMappingMethod;

    static MimeMappingWrapper() {
        // dirty trick - Assembly.LoadWIthPartialName has been deprecated
        Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("System.Web");
        Type t = ass.GetType("System.Web.MimeMapping");

        getMimeMappingMethod = t.GetMethod("GetMimeMapping", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a MIME type depending on the passed files extension
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">File to get a MIME type for</param>
    /// <returns>MIME type according to the files extension</returns>
    public static string GetMimeMapping(string fileName) {
        return (string)getMimeMappingMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { fileName });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any problem with avoiding the dirty hack by referencing a public type? `Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Web.HttpApplication))`.  As long as the method and referenced type don't change or disappear, that is... ?

Comment: I like your variable name for Assembly.

Answer (score 8):

*Cross-posting from [Why would Reflection search suddenly not find anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9144840/1149773)*

The good news is that the [`MimeMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160668%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and its [`GetMimeMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method seem like they might be made public in .NET 4.5.

However, this means that the code given in the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302264/how-do-i-get-the-mime-type-of-a-file-being-requested-in-asp-net-c#1357617) would break, since it’s only searching for `GetMimeMapping` among `NonPublic` methods.

To ensure compatibility with .NET 4.5 (but preserve functionality in .NET 4.0 and earlier), change…

```
getMimeMappingMethod = t.GetMethod("GetMimeMapping", 
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

…to:

```
getMimeMappingMethod = t.GetMethod("GetMimeMapping",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: nice one..although I don't get it. I am still on .NET 4 and yet the framework seems to behave like you described (which is like in .NET 4.5)..very strange

Comment: @mare you may have .NET 4.5 installed -- it's an in-place upgrade so the assemblies will have the new code at runtime but VS restricts you at compile time to the code available to .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

This information is in the registry, in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<file_extension>\Content Type`

```
using(var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(".htm"))
{
    string mimeType = key.GetValue("Content Type") as string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the technical requirements I was handed dictate no registry access.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question properly, you are serving static files and want to be able to do processing on a static file request in order to decide whether or not the user has access to that file. (based on MIME type)

If you map all files requests through a custom IHttpHandler (see the handlers section of your web.config file), you should be able to accomplish this.

In ProcessRequest (or BeginProcessRequest if you implement an asynchronous handler), you can call HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Path) (might be a better way to do that) to get the current static file being requested.

You can then analyze the extension of that file to make your decision.

Not sure if thats what you want, but hopefully it helps

Comment: That's very close to what I want, but I was hoping there was a more automatic way of doing it, rather than analyzing the extension. Something more along the lines of Request.MIMEType. Thank you for your input!