# MP4 content type returned as different MIME type in different browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, mime-types, content-type, mime

I have an ASP.NET application built using C# for the backend. I have a form that uploads a pdf and checks the MIME type, application/pdf, to verify it's a valid file. I need to do this on a seperate form for MP4 files but it didn't seem to work. It always returned false. I checked the returned MIME type FileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType in webkit which was perfectly accurate. Firefox 5 and IE 8, however, tested for text/csv and application/octet-stream, respectively. This makes absolutely no sense to me. I also tried mapping extensions to the correct MIME types in the web.config file like so:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
</staticContent>
```

And in the backend CS file I used this to test the posted file's content type:

```
if (file.PostedFile.ContentType == "video/mp4" || 
    file.PostedFile.ContentType == "video/mpeg" || 
    file.PostedFile.ContentType == "video/ogg" || 
    file.PostedFile.ContentType == "video/quicktime" || 
    file.PostedFile.ContentType == "video/webm") 
        return true;
else
        return false;
```

Also please note I am using the local development server that comes with VS

Answer (score 4):

It **is the browser** on the client side **that determines the content type** that gets **sent to the server**. That is the browser sends the header that ASP.NET uses to fill the HttpPostedFile.ContentType property.

**You can't change this with IIS staticContent mime mappings**, those settings apply only to files sent by the server to the client (not the other way around).

You'd better **use some custom code in your c# method** before the if-else block you posted, to (attempt to) **determine the** real **mime type with a server side check**.
Take a look at those two methods, that lead to different results and performance:

1. [Use reflection to call to a method in a *internal* .NET framework class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302264/how-do-i-get-the-mime-type-of-a-file-being-requested-in-asp-net-c/1357617#1357617) (this simply matches the file extension with those known to the framework itself)
2. [Use an un-managed call to a IE dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81283/asp-net-how-to-detect-file-upload-mime-type/1238450#1238450) (this method should guess the mime type looking for *magic bytes* inside the file, [as you can read in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107%28VS.85%29.aspx))

*Note: generally speaking you should always check/determine the content type on the server and never rely on the one sent by the client (never trust HttpPostedFile.ContentType): it can be accidentally wrong (as happened to you), purposely changed by some hacky user, wrong because of a browser not complying to some standard (IE is known to send wrong mime types for some image formats)...*

Comment: Would like to comment to warn everyone to double check that IIS (at the root level or the site instance) isn't overwriting the given mime type. Had a big problem with properly encoded videos not playing on Safari mobile because of this issue!