# HTML5 video with video.js not working in Safari

Tags: safari, html5-video, video.js

I have a private website that hosts training videos using the HTML5 video tag and the video.js plugin.  It was working in Chrome/Firefox/Safari up until last Spring, but now the videos no longer work in Safari.  They work fine in Chrome and Firefox.  I upgraded to the latest video.js v4.12 and v5 but that has not helped.  You can view the broken code on this test page.

http://dev.investja.org/videojs_problem2.html

When you open the page and click on the video it works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If the headers from server come different than the file extension, then the browser may have problems in rendering it. For example, if you want to render a file from http://.../some_name.mp4 and the "Content-Type" header comes "video/mpeg" and not "video/mp4", then the video may be considered corrupted. (happened to me on IE11)

Answer (score 1):

It also doesn't play in a regular HTML5 video element in Safari: http://output.jsbin.com/rologupuko

The Content-Type header is stating an incorrect mime type. It should be `video/mp4`. That's enough to break playback in some browsers, try fixing that.

```
curl -I http://dev.investja.org/virtual/download/10/mp4/JA_Video
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Oct 2015 09:42:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.29
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="JA ISP Lesson 03 Video 03-720p.mp4"
Content-Length: 42346342
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public
Expires: Sun, 01 Nov 2015 09:42:56 GMT
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/mp4
```

Comment: Turns out this was my issue, thank for pointing out! I wrote a similar comment regarding this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6780676/3997521

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in js code:

```
var myVideo = videojs(videoEl, { controls: true });
```

and remove сontrols from you html code. 
               ,

Answer (score 0):

demo videojs work on safari
this is my demo codepen link
[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/yuchichang/pen/gOqRjLB)

```
 player.el_.querySelector('video').src = null;
 player.el_.querySelector('video').srcObject = stream;
 player.play();
```